# disable mouse/touchpad pointer acceleration & speed 18.04?

Tags: touchpad, mouse-pointer

Ubuntu 16.04 had options to

1. control pointer speed
2. disable/enable acceleration

but Ubuntu 18.04 does not have any of these options which makes it too irritating to use.
It would be so great if the mouse/touchpad (in the case of laptops) experience were similar to that of Windows.

Can I achieve similar behaviour in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Devices -> Mouse & Touchpad has "Mouse Speed".

[image]

Also, `gnome-tweaks` has a Mouse "Acceleration Profile" amongst other things.

[image]

Comment: read the post again, i'm asking to disable acceleration not reducing speed of cursor.

Comment: @PankajSaini  1. control pointer speed (screenshot 1 - "Mouse Speed" slider input) 2. disable/enable pointer acceleration (screenshot 2 - "Acceleration Profile" - Dropdown box - select "Flat")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xset m 0 0
```

then reboot.